# Return records from table where they have not been used in another table, 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return all records from NetworkDomain where any of these networks have not yet been assigned to a specific organization (In this case, OrgName1). So in the below example, If I want to return all networks that have not been assigned to OrgName1 (which the result should then be NetName2 and NetName3) how would I do this?
NOTE: I need the networks to be ordered ASC

Table Name = "BusinessOrganizationDomain"

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        OrgUUID      |      OrgName     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1111       |      OrgName1    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2222       |      OrgName2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Table Name = "BusinessOrganizationAuthorizedNetwork"

```
|        OrgUUID      |      NetUUID     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1111       |      5555        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2222       |      6666        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Table Name = "NetworkDomain"

```
|        NetUUID      |      NetName     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5555       |      NetName1    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          6666       |      NetName2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          7777       |      NetName3    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Simply LEFT JOIN to get required output I mean if any of them not assigned.

Comment: left join results in null records when there are no matches, so do a left join and WHERE NetName IS NULL or some such.

Comment: I tried to formulate a left join on these 3 tables and have not figured it out. Sorry, I am a novice in SQL. I know how to left join and condition a NULL with 2 tables, but not the above case for 3 tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is NOT EXISTS predicate

```
SELECT * FROM NetworkDomain nd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM BusinessOrganizationAuthorizedNetwork bn 
  INNER JOIN BusinessOrganizationDomain bd 
     ON bd.OrgUUID = bn.orgUUID AND bn.NetUUID = nd.NetUUID AND bd.OrgName = 'OrgName1'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Not sure if you're trying to choose org based on the name, or the ID, so here's both.

**By name:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT nd.* FROM NetworkDomain nd
LEFT JOIN BusinessOrganizationAuthorizedNetwork boan ON boan.NetUUID = nd.NetUUID
LEFT JOIN BusinessOrganizationDomain bod ON bod.OrgUUID = boan.OrgUUID
WHERE bod.OrgName IS NULL
ORDER BY nd.NetName
```

Comment: The above will return the authorized users I guess. OP wanted the names those aren't assigned.

Comment: *"So in the below example, If I want to return all networks that have not been assigned to OrgName1"* - Names that have not been assigned to `OrgName1`, not names that haven't been assigned whatsoever, unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: I may have worded that wrong. I want to return networks that have not been assigned whatsoever. Can you edit to accommodate this?

Comment: You are getting closer. This resulted in all non assigned netwotks. However, I need to specify an organization name. All networks should be returned, except those assigned to 'insertorganizationnamehere'

Comment: I feel like you've given me contradictory information. The first query I had returned all networks except those assigned to `name here`, including unassigned. You then told me you only want unassigned names. You're essentially asking me to revert to what I had originally. Can you clarify?

Comment: Can you revert to your original query. Maybe I copied it wrong. See answer by Serg, his query accomplished what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will help.

**Order by NetName**

```
select nd.NetName 
from
BusinessOrganizationDomain bod inner join 
BusinessOrganizationAuthorizedNetwork boan 
on boan.OrgUUID = bod.OrgUUID
inner join 
NetworkDomain nd
on nd.NetUUID != boan.NetUUID
where bod.OrgName='OrgName1'
ORDER by nd.NetName
```

**Order by NetUUID**

```
select nd.NetName 
from
BusinessOrganizationDomain bod inner join 
BusinessOrganizationAuthorizedNetwork boan 
on boan.OrgUUID = bod.OrgUUID
inner join 
NetworkDomain nd
on nd.NetUUID != boan.NetUUID
where bod.OrgName='OrgName1'
ORDER by nd.NetUUID
```

Comment: This worked, but ONLY when an organization contained 1 network. If my organization contained 2 networks, your query returned duplicate records for non matches, and returned 1 record for matches